# How can I run this Polyglot token/tag extractor in PyCharm?

Tags: command-line, pycharm, named-entity-recognition, polyglot

I am evaluating various named entity recognition (NER) libraries, and I'm trying out [Polyglot](https://polyglot.readthedocs.io/en/latest/NamedEntityRecognition.html#example).

Everything seems to be going well, but the instructions tell me to use this line in the command prompt:

```
!polyglot --lang en tokenize --input testdata/cricket.txt |  polyglot --lang en ner | tail -n 20
```

...which should give (in the example) this output:

```
,               O
which           O
was             O
equalled        O
five            O
days            O
ago             O
by              O
South           I-LOC
Africa          I-LOC
in              O
their           O
victory         O
over            O
West            I-ORG
Indies          I-ORG
in              O
Sydney          I-LOC
.               O
```

That's exactly the kind of output I need for my project, and it works exactly like I need it to work; however, I need to run that within my PyCharm interface, not the command line, and store the results in a pandas dataframe.  How do I translate that command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming polyglot is installed correctly and proper environment is selected in pycharm. If not install polyglot in a `new conda environment` with necessary requirements. Create a new project and select that existing conda environment in pycharm. If `language embeddings`, `ner` models are not `downloaded` then they should be downloaded.

**Code:**

```
from polyglot.text import Text

blob = """, which was equalled five days ago by South Africa in the victory over West Indies in Sydney."""
text = Text(blob)
text.language = "en"


## As list all detected entities
print("As list all detected entities")
print(text.entities)

print()

## Separately shown detected entities
print("Separately shown detected entities")
for entity in text.entities:
    print(entity.tag, entity)

print()

## Tokenized words of sentence
print("Tokenized words of sentence")
print(text.words)

print()

## For each token try named entity recognition.
## Not very reliable it detects some words as not English and tries other languages.
## If other embeddings are not installed or text.language = "en" is commented then it may give error.
print("For each token try named entity recognition")
for word in text.words:
    text = Text(word)
    text.language = "en"

    ## Separately
    for entity in text.entities:
        print(entity.tag, entity)
```

**Output:**

```
As list all detected entities
[I-LOC(['South', 'Africa']), I-ORG(['West', 'Indies']), I-LOC(['Sydney'])]

Separately shown detected entities
I-LOC ['South', 'Africa']
I-ORG ['West', 'Indies']
I-LOC ['Sydney']

Tokenized words of sentence
[',', 'which', 'was', 'equalled', 'five', 'days', 'ago', 'by', 'South', 'Africa', 'in', 'the', 'victory', 'over', 'West', 'Indies', 'in', 'Sydney', '.']

For each token try named entity recognition
I-LOC ['Africa']
I-PER ['Sydney']
```

Comment: That worked for me.  I didn't see the .words method.  I'll use a for loop to add the words and tokens to my dataframe.  Thanks!